# Unexpected Behaviour while trying to update database in consecutive requests - EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have been dealing with this for days

**Summary**

I am creating a Social site that will be the back bone for another web application. The hangup is when I submit a request to create a group all goes well, but if I attempt to submit this form again with different data I get a `DbEntityValidationException`. The exception is related to the `ApplicationUser` entry.

**Details**

When I start the Application in Debug mode and submit the Group creation form for the first time it will succeed, adding all the entities into the database as excepted. I have verified this and all looks good. While in the same Debug session, I change the information in the form, to create another group, and submit the form, which leads to the `DbEntityValidationException`.

The error is related the when I try to insert a `SocialGroupMemberModel` which contains a reference to the User, and other details related to the users status in the group. The User entry is being marked as `added` and EntityFramework is trying to insert the User instead of updating. I have attempted to set the Navigation (User) and set the ForeignKey (UserId), both lead to the same error.

- I am using `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();`
- In the Controller I use `ApplicationUserManager` to get the User Entity, I then pass this to the Repository to create the group (in either case, either passing the ID, or Entity itself, doesn't work the second time)

Group Creation Code:

```
        var groupInfo = new SocialGroupInfo
        {
            Created = DateTime.Now,
            Description = model.Description,
            ShortDescription = model.ShortDescription,
            Name = model.Name,
            Tags = TagRepo.GetTags(),
            Members = new List<SocialGroupMember>()// { member }
        };            



        var groupModel = new SocialGroupModel
        {
            Slug = model.Slug,
            Info = groupInfo
        };

        Context.SocialGroups.Add(groupModel);

        var member = new SocialGroupOwnerModel
        {
            Joined = DateTime.Now,
            UserId = creator
            //User = null
            //Group = groupInfo
        };

        groupInfo.Members.Add(member);

        //creator.SocialGroups.Add(member);

        SaveChanges();
```

The Validation Error is: "User name ** is already taken" so this leads me to believe that on the second attempt to add the new group, it is attempting to add a new user.

Please ask for any additional information needed, thanks.

Comment: Are you using two DbContext ?

Comment: Take a look for an inner exception. EF can provide more information about error.

Comment: @mo.esmp I thought that this might be the case, so as an experiment I manually created another DbContext within the Repository, this failed completely, can't track from two contexts. So I have to believe that I am getting the request DbContext from Owin

Comment: @JesseJames Unfortunately this is no help, the InnerException is "null" no other information given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by the IoC holding a reference to the previous DbContext, unsure as to why, but removing all usage of Autofac fixed the issue.

Very anticlimactic solution, but issue fixed...

Now the issue is to figure out why Autofac was behaving this way, all Debugging showed that the classes were created each request... but that is another question.